# Access outer function variables from inner function

Tags: javascript

How to change value of `x` in function A() from function B()

```
function A() {
    var x = 10; // Value to be changed
    function B() {
        var x = 20;
        // From here i want to change the value of x (i.e. x=10 to x=40)
    }
    B();
}

A();
```

Comment: Easy, just name your other variable `y`.

Comment: its a interview question both vaiables should be named as x

Comment: can you, inside `B()`, `return 40;`, then when calling B: `x = B();`

Comment: @Siu Why was it necessary to edit every post here without making any actual improvements? See [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, the following code is a solution:

```
function A() {
    var x = 10; // Value to be changed
    function B() {
        var x = 20;
        // From here i want to change the value of x (i.e. x=10 to x=40)
        changeX(40);
    }
    function changeX(y) {
        x = y;
    }
    B();
    alert(x);
}

A();
```

However there are more elegant approach, but it depends on your application.

Answer (score 10):

Do not use `var` when intending to overwrite the variable. Using `var` creates a new variable, local to the scope in which it is declared. That's why `x` is not changing on the outside.

```
function A() {
    var x = 10;
    function B() {
        x = 20; // change x from 10 to 20
    }

    B(); // x is now changed
}
```

Comment: lol I think that's the obvious answer... were we allowed to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
function A() {
    var x = 10; // Value to be changed
    function B() {
        var x = 20;
        return x; // Return new value of x
    }
    x = B(); // Set x to result returned by B(), i.e. the new value
}

A();
```

Answer (score 1):

the `var` statement will create new local variable. So in your example:

```
function A() {
    var x = 10; // You can think of it as A.x
    function B() {
        var x = 20; // And this as A.B.x
    }
}
```

Those two variables belong to different scope, if you want to access variable of an outer scope from within inner scope just access it, without re-declaring it.

You might want to checkout "JavaScript Language Specifications" document available at http://www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/tutorial/jsspec.pdf to understand how scopes, statements and other basics work in JavaScript.